# Variable get value only after the second run of the macro

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, variables

My problem is that variable1 does not get the "1" value. I have already checked several times that the investigated cells contain the "1111' value. If I run the macro 2nd time, the variable1 get the "1" value, but first time never. The correct workbook and sheet is activated (already checked). Variable1 is integer and public. The code is already tried in module and workbook too.

What can be the problem? Thanks is advance!

```
variable1 = 0

Workbooks.Open "workbook1.xlsx"

Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Activate

Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

For i = 1 To 300
    If Cells(i, 2) = "1111" Then
    variable1 = 1
    Else
    End If
Next i

If variable1 = 1 Then
    GoTo xxx
Else
End If
```

Also tried in the for loop the following, but the result is the same:

```
Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
```

If I open the "workbook1.xlsx" manually, than I run the macro, the result is OK.

I have also tried a 5 sec waiting time after opening the workbook, but the result is NOK.

Comment: Does the cell contain the value (a number) or a text?

Comment: Shrotter, if the cell format would be the problem, I think the second run should give the same result (variable1=0). I have already tried cells(i,2).value="1111", but the result is the same.

Black cat, the "Workbook1" already contains the "1111" value befor the opening and running the macri.

Comment: You can try _If Cells(i, 2) = 1111 Then_ . So you don't compare to a string

Comment: You should learn how to code without using activate or select. That said: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint to the beginning of the code (maybe the top of the loop) and step through the code to watch what is going on.

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Shrotter, I have already tried with "1111" and 1111 too, the result is the same.

Comment: Shrotter, you were right. I have only tried cells(i,2).value only with "1111" and cells(i.2) with 1111 and "1111" that was the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used, cleaned up your code a bit but kept most like you had it so it's easily understandable where the error may lie:

```
Option Explicit
Public variable1 As Integer
Sub test()
    variable1 = 0
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Q:\Test\TestFile.xlsx") 'change this to your actual path
    Dim i As Long
    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
        For i = 1 To 300
            'Debug.Print .Cells(i, 2).Value 'for checking the values while testing
            If .Cells(i, 2).Value = "1111" Then
                variable1 = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
        
    If variable1 = 1 Then
        GoTo xxx
    End If
    Debug.Print "Alas, no success :c"
    Exit Sub
xxx:
    Debug.Print "Success!"
End Sub
```

I had hidden 2 1111 as numbers in the the B-column and one "1111" (text) further down and it went straight to xxx when it found the text "1111". Hope this helps you see where you went wrong but do let me know if this doesn't work for you either.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! But unfortunately it does not work. I always get 0 as variable value. I put the following after with and before the for loop: .cells(7,2)="test" -> and it works ("test" is in the correct cell), so the for loop is working on the right wb and worksheet.

I put the following in the for loop: msgbox(.cells(i,2)) and it works, and I see the "1111" value in the msgbox, so it should be okay. But the result is still NOK.

My code was OK when I opened the workbook manually, then started the macro. If the macro opened the workbook, the result was NOK. It is strange...

Comment: Are your values in the B-column text or numbers?

Comment: Issue found. I copied the values to an other workbook and I changed the format from general to number and now the result is OK. So it can be the root cause. But I still do not understand, how can be the result good (with general format) if I run the macro 2 times? The format is the same as in case of the first run...

Comment: I don't know why it's ok the second time other than there being a recalculation of some sort like when you'd have a formula in a text-formatted cell and change the format to general but it not calculating it anew. The code I provided worked fine the first time running it with it searching for a 1111 (text), and it would work fine if I adjusted it to `.Cells(i, 2).Value = 1111` if I wanted to search for a number. Sometimes I just have to throw in the towel and admit defeat to finding the root cause because it would take up too much time. Just remember = 1111 for number, ="1111" for text.

Comment: .Cells(i,2).Value = 1111 is the solution, now it works!  I have already tried before cells(i,2).value="1111" but with "1111". So it was wrong. Many thanks! :)

Comment: That's what Shrotter was talking about btw, I'm glad it worked out for you now though :)